# Explanation for recursive function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

here is the code.

```
1| def count_up(start):
2|     if start <= 0:
3|         print(start)
4|     else:
5|         count_up(start - 1)
6|         print(start)
7| count_up(5)
```

I don't understand why Line 6 ever get executed at all? In Line 5 we've jumped back into the function again from the top, and we keep doing that and decrementing the value of "start" by 1 each time until it reaches 0, at which point Lines 2 and 3 are executed and then the function is over.

It seems to me this code should just print "0", but it prints 0,1,2,3,4,5 when I ran it myself. I just don't see why Line 6 ever gets executed.
thank you.

Comment: Each invocation of this function gets its own call frame and (almost) every function call eventually returns to the caller. When `count_up(0)` returns, it picks up the execution for `count_up(1)` at Line 6, when `count_up(1)` returns it picks up the execution for `count_up(2)` at Line 6 and so on

Comment: The same reason `print("hi"); print("bye");` <-- why does `print("bye")` ever get called? Because eventually `print("hi")` returns and execution continues on the next line. It's no different with recursion, a copy of the function is spawned in its own frame with different arguments, it runs and eventually returns control back to the caller, which just happens to be a call frame running the same piece of source code.

Comment: can anybody write out what happens line by line please?

Comment: Try pythontutour.com next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `count_up(5)`: the condition is false, call the function again as `count_up(5-1)`
2. `count_up(4)`: the condition is false, call the function again as `count_up(4-1)`
3. `count_up(3)`: the condition is false, call the function again as `count_up(3-1)`
4. `count_up(2)`: the condition is false, call the function again as `count_up(2-1)`
5. `count_up(1)`: the condition is false, call the function again as `count_up(1-1)`
6. `count_up(0)`: the condition is true, print 0, return to the previous call
7. after returning into `count_up(1)`, print 1, return to the previous call
8. after returning into `count_up(2)`, print 2, return to the previous call
9. after returning into `count_up(3)`, print 3, return to the previous call
10. after returning into `count_up(4)`, print 4, return to the previous call
11. after returning into `count_up(5)`, print 5, return to the command line